# use of "ein" prefix?

Tags: verb-usage, prefix

What is the difference between the various use of schenken and einschenken.

> Mit dem Spielgerät hatte er nämlich dem FC Granada gerade fünf Tore eingeschenkt.
>
> Schenke Wein aus der Flasche ein!

einschenken + Akk. oder Dativ

Comment: Where do you see Dativ? "Fünf Tore" - Akkusativ. "(den) Wein" is Akkusativ too. "(aus) der Flasche" is in Dative because of preposition "aus" and has nothing to do with "einschenken".

Comment: "Dem FC Granada" is dative. Dative and accusative are used the same ways as in "schenken", "geben" etc. The receiver (if present) is in dative, and what is given is in accusative.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Do you think the second sentence uses *schenken*? It uses *einschenken* as well. The cases would be unchanged in both sentences if you replaced *einschenken* by *schenken*. In the first sentence this is because the dative is used in a way that has little to do with the verb itself (dative indicates an action is done *for* someone). In the second sentence it is because the dative is governed by the preposition *aus*, not by the verb.

Comment: Dative can be used in a lot of unexpected places: "Der Maler streicht meiner Oma den Gartenzaun" - Nothing specific with your specific verb.

Comment: @tofro Well, your example is not an unexpected place for Dativ :) It's actually very expected in this case.

Comment: @Eller - for an English-speaking native, it is. English doesn't know *dativus commodi*

Answer (score 2):

`ein` adds a connotation of insertion.

Some examples:

- `schenken` means to gift.
- `einschenken` has two meanings:

  - to pour (in that sense also *gift a drink*) something *into* a (e.g.) cup.
  - in the context of soccer, it means the same like the next word.
- `geben` means to hand over.
- `eingeben` means to type (hand over information) something *into* a machine.
- `zahlen` means to pay.
- `einzahlen` means to *place on* deposit.
- `laufen` means to run.
- `einlaufen` has two meanings:

  - to *enter* a certain area (e.g. goal) by running
  - to warm up for a run

Remark: Using the phrase `Tore einschenken` is very uncommon in the Southern parts of Austria (only `Tore schießen` is common here). But I guess it is quite common in Germany.

But it is wrong to assume, you can prepend `ein` to every verb to add this connotation.

Comment: As far as I know "jemandem einschenken" in the context of sports means "to win big", "to blow away the other team". The meaning "making goals" is a bit unusual but related. This meaning of "einschenken" is similar to "es jemandem geben" meaning "to tell s.o. off" or even "to beat s.o. up", depending on the context.

Comment: @RHa Doesn't seem to be a contradiction to what I wrote. Thanks for the valuable addition.